# Checking for an specific date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update an invoice value that currently "Invoice Date: Due Upon Receipt”. 
I need to make it read "June 1, 2020".  After June 1, 2020 it will need to revert back to read "Due Upon Receipt".

I am trying to figure it out, but I cannot adjust my machine's date settings because they are managed by the company.
So I am using a date of February 1, 2020 instead.

I would like to ask if how I am doing my query that returns the desired value, looks correct or if I need to make a change to make it more efficient.

This is what I got:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, GETDATE()))) >= '02/01/2020'
        THEN 'Due Upon Receipt'
        ELSE 'February 1, ' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) [Due Date]
    END
```

Comment: I suggest this should be 2 columns. *"June 1, 2020"* is clearly a date, not a string, and should be stored in a `date` (or other date time data type) column,  not a `varchar`. Then you should have a different column for the "status"(?), which can have the value `NULL`, until needed.

Comment: Also be careful with date literals. "02/01/2020" might be considered Feb 1st or Jan 2nd depending on localization settings. You should use the ANSI compliant YYYYMMDD for string literals. In your case it would be '20200201'. That string literal will ALWAYS be interpreted correctly regardless of any local settings.

Comment: This is a value that goes on a report/invoice only, and this report will always be used in the United States.

Comment: Here is a sql fiddle to demonstrate the challenges with literal date strings. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/73226

Comment: For an isolated value in a report I think your case expression is probably ok. It is generally not a good idea to format a date value but with only a single language in a single country it is probably ok.

Comment: *"this report will always be used in the United States"* I work in the UK, and I only have applications that are used by UK users. I have an application that is written by a UK vendor, where I *have* to set their login language to `ENGLISH` (not `BRITISH`) because they pass dates in the format `yyyy-MM-dd` to a `datetime` column... (don't get me started on the fact that I specifically asked them if their application was language agnostic, and was told "yes"... We almost a whole day cause of their stupidity). Just because you *think* everything is American doesn't mean it will be.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN GETDATE() >= '2020-02-01'
             THEN 'Due Upon Receipt'
             ELSE CONCAT('February 1, ',YEAR(GETDATE())) 
        END as [Due Date]
```

Your query uses February for the cut-off, not June, but it is the same idea.